# ImportError: cannot import name '__check_build'

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, k-means

I can't seem to get from sklearn.cluster import KMean to work in Python I did the whole pip install scipy/numpy and they are installed in python but I can't get the KMeans into it at the moment I have found a load of ones that are similar to my problem but I can't seem to get it working with mine.

When I do from sklearn.cluster import KMeans I just get an error that says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
import sklearn
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
from . import __check_build
ImportError: cannot import name '__check_build'
```

Can someone please help me I would be forever grateful!!!

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if you don't have `scipy` installed, so run this in your command prompt:

```
pip install scipy
```

Comment: I already have it installed because if I type it again I just get Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade) : scipy in c:\python34\lib\site-packages

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo pip install scipy
```

Then in Python:

```
import scipy
```